# NSFetchedResultsController not resorting content changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to figure out why my `NSFetchedResultsController` instance seems to be ignoring it's `sortDescriptor`s when content changes. All delegate methods, etc., are called, but when the relevant property that I'm sorting on changes, I only get an `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` change notification, and resorting of content has not occurred:

Here's how I'm creating the `NSFetchedResultsController` instance:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [UIApplication managedObjectContext];

_fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([MCCDBook class])];
_fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastOpened" ascending:true selector:@selector(compare:)]
];
_fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:_fetchRequest.entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:_fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionTitle" cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

Here's what the property that sorting is done on looks like:

[image]

And here is how I'm updating said property:

```
entity.lastOpened = [NSDate date];

[entity.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Any ideas? This one is puzzling me.

**EDIT:**

I've done some more testing, and it appears the problem is this: `NSFetchedResultsController` is only bothering to do any resorting on the original `sortDescriptors`. If I change the request's `sortDescriptors` or it's `predicate` after initialization of `NSFetchedResultsController` (and I am calling `performFetch:`), my delegate methods are called, but the `fetchedObjects` does not resort itself.

Comment: try this [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastOpened" ascending:YES]

Comment: @eddwinpaz Tried that - no difference. :/

Comment: I wonder whether the FRC is getting confused because you set the fetch's entity after you set the sort descriptors?

Comment: @pbasdf I only started setting `entity` to see if would fix this bug. It doesn't work without it either.

Comment: I see you are using a sectionNameKeyPath.  Does it work any better without?  How is sectionTitle defined?

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks for trying to help. I solved part of the problem below - could you take a look?

Comment: This was my fault - re-reading the documentation I realized was breaking the cardinal rule, and modifying the `predicate` & `fetchRequest` after initializing `NSFetchedResultsController`. I removed the code where I was doing that and it started working. However, does anyone have better solutions to this problem other than recreating the `NSFetchedResultsController` every time I need to change something?

Comment: I just realized I was doing things correctly - I've been calling `performFetch:` anytime I modified the NSFetchRequest...I'll keep looking.

Comment: @mattsven I'm pretty sure if you use `performFetch` it does not fire the delegate methods - so you will have to do a full `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: @pbasdf I'm referring to Core Data updates that occur after the `performFetch:`

Comment: @pbasdf I did some more testing, and I found out the nature of the issue. I added it as an edit to my question above.

Comment: Could you initialise a completely new FRC with the new predicate and sort descriptors (rather than just performFetch on the existing FRC)?

Comment: @pbasdf I could, I guess that's my only option. Want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, it seems that the FRC gets confused if you vary the fetch request's predicate or sort descriptors on the fly.  If you need to vary them, then instantiate a completely new FRC with the new predicate and sort descriptors.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote a method that recreates the `NSFetchedResultsController` anytime I need to change the `sortDescriptors` (it seems to be cool about predicates). Thanks for the help again.